# javascript to change language on google,com

Tags: javascript

all! I have to solve this task , and ask your help:

Use JavaScript to change interface language at  https://www.google.com/

Expecting result:  — JS-script that changes language of the page when you put it in browser console.

Comment: If you were asked to solve this problem, the people asking you to do so may have a reason to believe you capable of solving the problem; may I ask where you got stuck, and what code you came up with? Where did it fail, and in what way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google uses a search parameter named `hl` to change the language of the site, you can set that manually with `window.location.search = 'hl=en-US'`. Replace `en-US` with the language code you want to set.

Sites usually guess your language based on different parameters, such as subdomain, query string (like Google), your location, browser language, cookies, localStorage etc. If you open google.com in an incognito window and change the language on the cookie consent modal, you can see the query string change to the selected language.